# Stored procedures architecture - should my MVC application be handling stored procedures, or should something akin to a "worker role" take care of it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table in my database that needs some form of pruning every 15 minutes.  I figure I have two approaches:

1. Expose a WebAPI endpoint in my MVC app that gets hit every 15 minutes from a worker role in another process.  Simply send a GET request every 15 minutes so my MVC app handles it.
2. Have my worker role not send a request to the endpoint, but actually perform the db pruning within the process. Instead of sending a GET request to my MVC, it's 100% separate and goes into the db to make changes with its own connection string.

I'm new to the .NET world and have no idea what the standard approach is here - any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: please define "pruning"

Comment: @Sico - every 15 minutes I delete all records that are more than one hour old

Comment: adding to the comments below, If this is an archiving process in the database, might be simpler to make it a scheduled sql job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pro of putting it into the MVC application is that it becomes portable; this also becomes a con because you're *pruning* the database. The pro of another process is that it's isolated; the con is just that as well - the code isn't easily accessible from anywhere else.

If this is strictly an administrative task and doesn't need portability; make it its own process.

Answer (score 1):

If it needs pruning every 15 min and has no businessmen logic associated wit this process it may be simpler to schedule a task to do this for you on the machine that has access to db. I don't see a reason to mix concerns.